# How to set version of schema using jaxb2-maven-plugin when generating xsd with SchemaGen?

Tags: xml, maven, jaxb, jaxb2-maven-plugin

This is my plugin:

```
       <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>schemagen</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>schemagen</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

And this is the root element:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "FooBar")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class FooBarEnvelope {
   //other elements not listed
}
```

When I run maven it will generate this xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:element name="FooBar" type="FooBarEnvelope"/>
    <!-- other elements -->
</xs:schema>
```

and it works great, but now I want to set the version of schema:

```
<xs:schema version="5.2.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

How can I do that?